# How to change the Ubuntu Touch calendar to Hijri?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, calendar, localization

I want to change the calendar to Hijri Calender in the Ubuntu-Phone. How to change those month settings?

Answer (score 0):

You can install islamic calendar in Ubuntu

PPA for Hijra:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sabily.team/ppa && sudo apt-get -q update
sudo apt-get install hijra-applet
```

official
[website](http://ojuba.org/wiki/hijra/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%AD%D8%A9_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D9%88%D9%84%D9%89)

Comment: Will this work for Ubuntu Touch?